# Как задать номер строки среди групп строк во всей таблице?

Tags: sql, sql-server

С помощью запроса

```
SELECT d.*
      , (SELECT count(d1.id) 
         from dbo.document d1 
         WHERE d1.applicationId = d.applicationId 
             AND d1.borrowerId = d.borrowerId 
             AND d1.id < d.id
       ) AS position
FROM dbo.document d
```

я могу сделать выборку, в которой будут указаны номера документов (по порядку, отсчёт с `0`), сгруппированных по `applicationId`  и `borrowerId`.

*Вопрос*: мне нужно записать эти значения в таблицу для хранения. Как это сделать?

Попробовал с помощью

```
UPDATE dbo.document
SET docNo = (
         SELECT count(d1.id) 
         from dbo.document d1 
         WHERE d1.applicationId = applicationId 
              AND d1.borrowerId = borrowerId 
              AND d1.id < id
     )
```

Но этот запрос проставил только нули.

Comment: а функции `row_number` вы не пробовали использовать для нумерации? вместо всей этой портянки c подзапросом нужно только `row_number() over (partition by applicationId, borrowedId order by id)`.

Comment: И почему в первом случае в условиях вы используете алиасы для обоих таблиц, а в update вы почему то не используете алиаса для одной из таблиц и все условия вроде `d1.id < id` обращаются к одной и той же таблице ...

Comment: @Mike потому что имя целиком писать лень, а алиас в update не знает как? :)

Comment: @Mike dbForge по какой-то причине ругается, когда я добавляю алиас к таблице, которая обновляется.

Comment: это потому что синтаксис команды не прочитали, и пытаетесь написать `update table as t`

Comment: А какой вообще смысл в номере строки, если у Вас нигде нет `ORDER BY`? Вы же в курсе, что при двух последовательных запусках Вашего запроса сервер вполне может выдать строки в разном порядке?

Comment: @Yaant Не имеет значения, мне просто нужно проставить нумерацию.

Comment: @Yaant там `id < id` условие считает нормально, номера будут корректны

Comment: `update X set ... FROM dbo.document X` просто посмотрите примеры с join в документации https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql

Comment: @teran А, да, это я не сообразил чего-то.

Comment: @teran, пишите ответ